# Comparator as lambda expression in PriorityQueue

Tags: java-8, comparator, priority-queue

Can you please point out where am I going wrong?

**Works fine**:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0] );
```

**error**: array required, but Object found

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue(10, ( (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0] ));
```

**error**: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue(10, ( (int[] a, int[] b) -> a[0] - b[0] ));
```

Answer (score -1):

The argument requires arr.length which is an int, but you are passing an arr which I assume is the array.

Comment: Updated question to remove ambiguity. 

PriorityQueue constructor: PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)